# How to move the image inside rectangle in p5js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I'm currently doing a project regarding p5.js and I need to do the following:

**Input**: given image and rectangle;

**Algorithm**: move the image inside the rectangle. By saying moving, I mean when the mouse is clicked, move the whole image to match the size of the rectangle by showing only portion of the image (size of the rectangle).

**Output**: dragging image inside the rectangle.

**Update:** When I import an image with React input form, it does not change the current image in P5 even I call the `p5.redraw()` function.

My current code is moving the image, but I need an image to be inside the rectangle and show only part of the image that is this size of the rectangle. The code is written in React:

```
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
  let backgroundImage;
  let dragging = false; // Is the object being dragged?
  let rollover = false; // Is the mouse over the ellipse?

  let x, y, w, h; // Location and size
  let offsetX, offsetY; // Mouseclick offset

  const setup = (p5, parentRef) => {
    p5.createCanvas(1000, 500).parent(parentRef);
    // Starting location
    x = 350;
    y = 50;

    const url =
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png";
    backgroundImage = p5.loadImage(url);
    // Dimensions
    w = 700;
    h = 700;
  };

  const draw = (p5) => {
    p5.background(233);
    if (
      p5.mouseX > x &&
      p5.mouseX < x + w &&
      p5.mouseY > y &&
      p5.mouseY < y + h
    ) {
      rollover = true;
    } else {
      rollover = false;
    }

    // Adjust location if being dragged
    if (dragging) {
      x = p5.mouseX + offsetX;
      y = p5.mouseY + offsetY;
    }

    if (selectedFile != null) {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
      backgroundImage = p5.loadImage(url);
      // p5.image(backgroundImage, x, y, w, h);
      // p5.redraw();
      // backgroundImage = p5.loadImage(url, () => {
      //   p5.image(backgroundImage, x, y, w, h);
      //   p5.redraw();
      // });
    } else {
    }
    p5.image(backgroundImage, x, y);
    drawMaskOverlay(p5);
  };

  const drawMaskOverlay = (p5) => {
    p5.fill(255);
    p5.noStroke();
    p5.beginShape();
    // CW
    p5.vertex(0, 0);
    p5.vertex(p5.width, 0);
    p5.vertex(p5.width, p5.height);
    p5.vertex(0, p5.height);
    // cutout contour CCW
    p5.beginContour();
    p5.vertex(400, 100);
    p5.vertex(400, 400);
    p5.vertex(600, 400);
    p5.vertex(600, 100);
    p5.endContour();
    p5.endShape();
  };

  const mousePressed = (p5) => {
    if (
      p5.mouseX > x &&
      p5.mouseX < x + w &&
      p5.mouseY > y &&
      p5.mouseY < y + h
    ) {
      dragging = true;

      offsetX = x - p5.mouseX;
      offsetY = y - p5.mouseY;
    }
  };

  const mouseReleased = (p5) => {
    // Quit dragging
    dragging = false;
  };
```

to display it, I use the following code:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Select an image</h1>
        <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          id="file"
          // onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <Sketch
          // preload={preload}
          setup={setup}
          draw={draw}
          mouseReleased={mouseReleased}
          mousePressed={mousePressed}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I use [react-p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5) library.

You can see and test the code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vhupb5?file=src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick workaround is to simply overlay a cutout shape using [`beginContour()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginContour) / `endContour()`, thus only showing a portion of the image:

```js
let backgroundImage;
let dragging = false; 
let rollover = false; 

let x, y, w, h; // Location and size
let offsetX, offsetY; 

preload = () => {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png";
  backgroundImage = loadImage(url);
};

setup = () => {
  createCanvas(1000, 500);
  // Starting location
  x = 100;
  y = 100;

  // Dimensions
  w = 300;
  h = 400;
}

draw = () => {
  background(233);
  if (
    mouseX > x &&
    mouseX < x + w &&
    mouseY > y &&
    mouseY < y + h
  ) {
    rollover = true;
  } else {
    rollover = false;
  }
  if (dragging) {
    x = mouseX + offsetX;
    y = mouseY + offsetY;
  }

  image(backgroundImage, x, y, w, h);
  // noFill();
  // stroke(0);
  // rect(100, 100, 200, 300);
  drawMaskOverlay();
};

function drawMaskOverlay(){
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
  // CW
  vertex(0, 0);
  vertex(width, 0);
  vertex(width, height);
  vertex(0, height);
  // cutout contour CCW
  beginContour();
  vertex(100, 100);
  vertex(100, 400);
  vertex(300, 400);
  vertex(300, 100);
  endContour();
  endShape();
  
}

mousePressed = () => {
  if (
    mouseX > x &&
    mouseX < x + w &&
    mouseY > y &&
    mouseY < y + h
  ) {
    dragging = true;

    offsetX = x - mouseX;
    offsetY = y - mouseY;
  }
};

mouseReleased = () => {
  dragging = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If the project is a school project it's unclear whether the above will pass if it doesn't cover the materials taught. If it's a personal project, the above should be a simple enough workaround.

Other alternatives ways of showing parts of the image could be:

- working with p5.Image which has a [mask()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/mask) method (potentially in conjuction with [p5.Graphics](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Graphics) which would make it easy draw into and covert to a p5.Image via `get()`)
- with with p5.Image and instead of masking, clearing a blank (buffer) image and only copying a portion of `backgroundImage` (depending on it's dragged location) via [copy()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/copy) which would make it appear like `backgroundImage` is masked.

**Update** based on your file select comment here's a tweaked version of the above snippet:

```js
let backgroundImage;
let dragging = false; 
let rollover = false; 

let x, y, w, h; // Location and size
let offsetX, offsetY; 

preload = () => {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png";
  backgroundImage = loadImage(url);
};

setup = () => {
  createCanvas(1000, 500);
  // Starting location
  x = 100;
  y = 100;

  // Dimensions
  w = 300;
  h = 400;

  createFileInput(handleFile);
}

handleFile = (file) => {
  if (file.type === 'image') {
    backgroundImage = createImg(file.data, '');
    backgroundImage.hide();
  } else {
    backgroundImage = null;
  }
}

draw = () => {
  background(233);
  if (
    mouseX > x &&
    mouseX < x + w &&
    mouseY > y &&
    mouseY < y + h
  ) {
    rollover = true;
  } else {
    rollover = false;
  }
  if (dragging) {
    x = mouseX + offsetX;
    y = mouseY + offsetY;
  }
  // only render the image if it exists
  if(backgroundImage)
    image(backgroundImage, x, y, w, h);
  // noFill();
  // stroke(0);
  // rect(100, 100, 200, 300);
  drawMaskOverlay();
};

function drawMaskOverlay(){
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
  // CW
  vertex(0, 0);
  vertex(width, 0);
  vertex(width, height);
  vertex(0, height);
  // cutout contour CCW
  beginContour();
  vertex(100, 100);
  vertex(100, 400);
  vertex(300, 400);
  vertex(300, 100);
  endContour();
  endShape();
  
}

mousePressed = () => {
  if (
    mouseX > x &&
    mouseX < x + w &&
    mouseY > y &&
    mouseY < y + h
  ) {
    dragging = true;

    offsetX = x - mouseX;
    offsetY = y - mouseY;
  }
};

mouseReleased = () => {
  dragging = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dear George, thank you. Using vertexes actually did the job and I have modified the code. However, there is a strange problem appearing once I try to upload a new image in React input form and try to use it with p5 to change the current image. I have updated the code. The problem is that the current image does not change with new image even I call `p5.redraw()` function.

Comment: Dear Nijat, great to hear the answer above did thejob! Consider [voting and/or accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Can you please post a separate question regarding this new issue ? e.g. (image doesn't change after being swapped) that would make it easier to find/organise (rather than haivng one very long post that addresses more than one qustion). Feel free to link the other question for context. Try adding a console log in the ` if (selectedFile != null) {` condition and see if it behaves the way you expect it to or not...

Comment: ... Optionally, you can look into [p5's `createFileInput()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createFileInput) and load the image once in the handler (rather than many times per second in `draw()`)

Comment: Dear George. Thank you for the reply. I have accepted your answer as correct answer to my question.I wanted to create a new question, but as it is small bug, I didn't want to create separate issue for it. I have logged the `selectedFile` and that condition works fine and gets the image. I assume problem appears in `draw()` function as every second it draws the shapes. Do you mean to use backgroundImage variable with p5's `createFileInput` in another function? How can I actually trigger that handler in my `draw()` function then?

Comment: This method is getting the file from canvas itself, but I don't really want that. I will have an input field and I need to get the file from it. `createFileInput` is actually placing and positioning the file input inside the canvas.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time for a detailed answer. I've posted an updated snippet using `createFileInput` above. Feel free to use it or not. Hopefully it illustrates the event flow of loading one and using the image opposed to loading the image over and over again (which is what the code in your link does). Sure it's not using React, but when solving problems it's best to simplify as much as possible and isolate the issue. Hope the advice is useful

Comment: Thank you for the update, George. I will need to find a better way as you have mentioned.

Comment: I've finnally found a bit of time to address your comments in more detail. I know it's a small bug but I still believe it's useful to separate the mask issue from the image swap issue. Regaring `selectedFile` that didn't work fine for me. When I added a console log in the `if (selectedFile != null)` in `draw()` I saw the message logged many times per second. Ideally that loadImage call should happen once per user file selection event. I suppose you could set `selectedFile` back to null after loading the image to 'debounce' / ensure the load happens once, but it feels like a hacky workaround...

Comment: ...when it should be possible to simply add file select event and load the image there. I was suggesting `createFileInput` because it's already part of p5 and I was hoping this would make things simpler for you. It matters less which method you go for (manually using [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications) in plain JS, `createFileInput` in p5 or [using React](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-a-simple-form-submit-with-files-in-react). The idea is (as you can see in the File API docs) that you can listen for an event...

Comment: ...when a user selects a file. That event handler function is where you want to load the image and assign it to `backgroundImage` instead of `draw()`. I don't understand why you need to use `draw()` to check for the file selection and keep reloading the image over and over again (resulting in your small bug of the image never getting the change to load an display before the next load in an endless loop). The updated snippet above works without React and hopefully demonstrates listening to an event. If you don't need to use React don't. If you do, understand that...

Comment: ...you're using a file `<input>` which is outside the scope of your React App which in turn is a react-p5 app, so has some extra quirks in terms of scope/access. You will need to read/understand enough of how React works to be able to pull this off. It's not impossible: just need to read the docs, try out relevant info from the docs and, while testing bit by bit, apply what you've learned to reach your goal. Good luck!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. I have checked it, but still could not resolve the issue with React. With plain HTML it works, but in React application I cannot really make it work due to scope issue. I have created new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73110524/10489887) but could not get a response.

Comment: I could work with `createFileInput`, but I cannot in this project as I need to develop other things which should be done in React. I'm not really familiar with p5 and don't completely understand the scope to make it work in React. If you would check the code in StackBlitz and update there, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I could use handler to get the image, but the issue is that I cannot use `p5.createImage()` there because it will give `p5` undefined error as it is out of scope.

Comment: @NijatMursali Any joy with the solution provided for your new issue ?